# Kotlin type-safe typealiases

Tags: kotlin, type-alias

I use typealiases in my Kotlin code a lot, but I wonder if I can enforce type-safety on them.

```
typealias Latitude = Double
typealias Longitude = Double

fun someFun(lat: Latitude, lon: Longitude) {...}

val lat: Latitude = 12.34
val lon: Longitude = 56.78
someFun(lon, lat) // parameters are in a wrong order, but the code compiles fine
```

It would be nice if I could somehow prevent implicit casting between typealiases, helping to avoid such issues.

Of course, there is a problem, that the operations on basic types would be not available for typealiases, but it can be solved with extension functions (or casts).

I don't want to use data classes, holding a single field, because it seems a bit of overkill, especially for primitive types (or maybe I am wrong and they'll be optimized out?)

So the question: can I somehow enforce type-safety for typealiases?

Comment: Currently only way is to create explicit type. `class Latitude :  Double`. Or am I missing something here? The compiler will then enforce the typing, but you can still treat it as a Double in most places.

Comment: @Mikezx6r yes, you're missing several things: 1) You can't inherit from primitive types, 2) You can't inherit from final classes 3) This approach has runtime overhead

Comment: This is possible without experimental features as of Kotlin 1.5, added an answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Update for Kotlin 1.3

Inline classes are already available as of Kotlin 1.3 and currently are marked as experimental. [See the docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-classes.html#experimental-status-of-inline-classes)

### Original answer

Unfortunately you can't avoid this currently. There is a feature in progress - [inline classes (#9 in this document)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwAovUlww0CmVmNQTXd4TTdKYUU/view), which will solve the problem with the runtime overhead, while enforcing compile time type-safety. It looks quite similar to [Scala's value classes](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html), which are handy if you have a lot of data, and normal case classes will be an overhead.

Comment: A nice document. #4 would be a killer-feature :) Still, I don't understand why inline classes should provide the runtime overhead. Also, my problem could also be solved with smth like `strict typealias Longitude = Double` , where strict would mean that only explicit casts are allowed on the type.

Comment: There isn't any runtime overhead with inline classes, because the values are never boxed/unboxed, after the compiler finishes with the type checks on the AST, the values are left with the underlying type, so in your case both values will still be Long when the VM executes the code. What I referred to as a runtime overhead are case classes in Scala, when used just as type safe wrapper of a single value (and this is the main reason for Scala's SIP-15).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible with typealiases. The kotlin reference says:

> Type aliases do not introduce new types. They are equivalent to the
>   corresponding underlying types. When you add `typealias Predicate<T>`
>   and use `Predicate<Int>` in your code, the Kotlin compiler always expand
>   it to `(Int) -> Boolean`. Thus you can pass a variable of your type
>   whenever a general function type is required and vice versa:
>
> ```
> typealias Predicate<T> = (T) -> Boolean
>
> fun foo(p: Predicate<Int>) = p(42)
>
> fun main(args: Array<String>) {
>     val f: (Int) -> Boolean = { it > 0 }
>     println(foo(f)) // prints "true"
>
>     val p: Predicate<Int> = { it > 0 }
>     println(listOf(1, -2).filter(p)) // prints "[1]"
> }
> ```

See kotlin [type aliases](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/type-aliases.html).

tl;dr You have to use (data) classes

As the name typealias implies, a typealias is only a alias and not a new type. In your example `Latitude` and `Longitude` are `Ints`, independet from their names. To make them typesafe you have to declare a type. In theory you could inherit new types from `Int`. Since `Int` is a final class this is not possible. So its reqiuered to create a new class.

Comment: I've read this more than once. Questions are why it's done this way and how to bypass this limitation.

Comment: I added a short explanation why it's not possible. Hope it helps you :)

Comment: Int is not a final class, it's a primitive. Int? is a final class.

Comment: In kotlin `Int` is a final class. It extands `Number` and implements `Comparable<Int>`. Its declared in `kotlin.Primitives.kt`

Comment: This would be a possible solution too. You could create classes that extand `Number`. But I dont now how this interoperability and compatibility of such classes are.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [inline classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inline-classes.html) for this (since Kotlin 1.5). Inline classes are erased during complication, so at runtime `lat` and `lon` are just `double`s, but you get the benefit of the compile-time checks.

```
@JvmInline
value class Latitude(private val value: Double)

@JvmInline
value class Longitude(private val value: Double)

fun someFun(lat: Latitude, lon: Longitude) {
    println("($lat, $lon)")
}

fun main() {
    val lat = Latitude(12.34)
    val lon = Longitude(56.78)
    someFun(lon, lat) // Type mismatch: inferred type is Longitude but Latitude was expected
    someFun(lat, lon) // OK
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the difference between `typealias` and `inline classes` for the case of avoiding params wrong order:

**typeAlias:**

```
typealias LatitudeType = String
typealias LongitudeType = String

fun testTypeAlias() {
    val lat: LatitudeType = "lat"
    val long: LongitudeType = "long"

    testTypeAliasOrder(lat, long) // ok
    testTypeAliasOrder(long, lat) // ok :-(
}

fun testTypeAliasOrder(lat: LatitudeType, long: LongitudeType) {}
```

**inline classes:**

```
@JvmInline
value class Latitude(val lat: String)

@JvmInline
value class Longitude(val long: String)

fun testInlineClasses() {
    val lat = Latitude("lat")
    val long = Longitude("long")

    testInlineClassesOrder(lat, long) // ok
    testInlineClassesOrder(long, lat) // Compilation error :-)
}

fun testInlineClassesOrder(lat: Latitude, long: Longitude) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been interested in this topic for quite a while. This is what I came up with.

I would define an interface for an Id type and I would implement it:

```
interface UniqueId<T> {
    fun getId(): T
    fun toExternal(): String
}
data class UniqueIdImpl<T>(private val id: T) : UniqueId<T> {
    override fun getId(): T = id
    override fun toExternal(): String = "External-$id"
}
```

(For the sake of the example, I could have made it simpler by omitting the type parameter and just go for Int...)

Then you define your types like so, using delegation:

```
data class ClientId(private val id: UniqueId<Int>): UniqueId<Int> by id
data class OrderId(private val id: UniqueId<Int>): UniqueId<Int> by id
data class SomeId(private val id: UniqueId<UUID>): UniqueId<UUID> by id
```

And this is how to use them:

```
val clientId = ClientId(UniqueIdImpl(1))
val someId = SomeId(UniqueIdImpl(UUID.randomUUID()))
```

---

EDIT:

Well, you can get similar effect with abstract classes...

```
abstract class I<T>(private val i: T) {
    fun getId() = i
    fun toExternal() = "External-$i"
}

data class OtherId(private val i: Int) : I<Int>(i)
data class YetAnotherId(private val i: UUID) : I<UUID>(i)
```

Answer (score -1):

By defining `Latitude` and also `Longitude` as aliases for `Double` it can be seen as transitive aliases, i.e. you defined `Latitude` as an alias for `Longitude` and vice versa. Now, all three type names can be used interchangeably:

```
val d: Double = 5.0
val x: Latitude = d
val y: Longitude = x
```

You could, as an alternative, simply use parameter names to make clear what is being passed:

```
fun someFun(latitude: Double, longitude: Double) {
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val lat = 12.34
    val lon = 56.78
    someFun(latitude = lon, longitude = lat)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I was recently struggling with similar case. Inline classes are not the solution cause it forces me to use property wrapper.

Hopefully for me I've managed to solve my problem by inheritance delegation.

```
class ListWrapper(list: List<Double>): List<Double> by list
```

This approach allows us to operate directly on ListWrapper as on regular List. Type is strictly identified so it might be passed via the Koin dependency injection mechanism for example.

We can go even deeper:

```
class ListListWrapper(list: ListWrapper): ListWrapper by list
```

but this require us to "open" the parent class with reflection cause `@Suppress("FINAL_SUPERTYPE") does not work.

Unfortunately with primitives there is other issue, cause they somehow providing only empty private constructor and are initialized with some undocumented magic.

Comment: Don't blame me that it is out of topic, focus rather on the"smart" person who marked my question as duplicate of this one